# Herring is a fish

Tags: grammaticality

Consider this list of sentences which are designed to convey the idea that herring are fish.

1. Herring is a fish.
2. Herring are fish.
3. A herring is a fish.
4. All herring are fish.
5. The herring is a type of fish.

I think (2), (3), (4) and (5) are grammatically correct. However, I think (1) is grammatically incorrect because herring is a plural noun. Hence, you can't assign it to the expression "fish", which is being used as a singular noun in the first sentence unless you explicitly make the expression "herring" a singular noun in the first sentence by saying "a herring" or "the herring".

My question is, is the first sentence "Herring is a fish," grammatically incorrect?

**Clarifications**

Herring is not a person's name.

Comment: 1 can be correct if 'Herring' is a person's name.  However, outside of that context, I would agree with you.  That said, what is your actual question?  Are you asking if you're correct?

Comment: @childofsoong I added some clarification to my question.

Comment: Herring can be a plural form as in (2), and also refers to a *single species* of fish - I think the first construction can also be correct.

Comment: 1. A fish is herring is *singular*.

Comment: *Herring* is a species of fish.  Hence "Herring is a fish."

Comment: @HotLicks Well the monkey is also a species, but "Monkey is an animal" is definitely wrong.

Comment: @michaelsnowden - How so?  Explain it to me.

Comment: Man is an animal.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not great at grammar, so I can't prove it, but it sounds wrong to me. Also, http://www.gingersoftware.com/grammarcheck thinks it's wrong. My idea is that we can say "the monkey" is a family/species, and that we can say "the herring" is a species/family, and that we can say "herring" is a species/family, but we can't say "monkey" is a species/family.

Comment: Different animal names work differently. With some the species name is the same as the name as the individual animal (herring, deer, cod, man) and with some it isn't and we put 'the' before it (monkey, armadillo, ostrich). I believe its related to whether the plural is the same as the singular.

Comment: At least when you think of food, i'd say 1) is correct: sage is a herb, pepper is a spice, cod is a fish, and so is herring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Herring can refer to one fish, or many fish - it is its own plural. It is also the name of a family of fish. So:

> This herring here, and those two herring there, all belong to the family *herring*.

The family can be referred to as *herring* or *the herring*.

**All your sentences are correct.**

1. Herring [the family] is a fish.
2. Herring [the plural] are fish.
3. A herring [the singular] is a fish.
4. All herring [the plural] are fish.
5. The herring [the family] is a type of fish.

Number 1 is a bit borderline, and might be better replaced by 5. If you are dealing with a strictly technical grammatical analysis you might rule it out. If you are looking at its acceptability in real life, it's fine.

Lots of animal names follow the same pattern, including cod, sturgeon, pike.